# Does signing a offer letter mean I am tied to them?

Tags: job-offer, canada

I recently signed a post grad position starting in September (9 months away). The offer is fairly laxed, it doesn't have a set start date except (August 2017) as they are still finalizing details of the development program.

I am currently thinking of job hunting elsewhere to see how other companies are as well.  Is this an option for me in Canada? Since I have accepted their offer does this mean that I am employed by them already or can I just change my mind and withdraw my acceptance with no serious repercussions?

Comment: you're asking the wrong question, as Joe's comment proves. Not being "at will" doesn't mean you have to take the job.

Comment: Why would you sign something when you don't know what that signature will mean? The general question may be answerable but what your options are is something to discuss with a legal professional.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you provide "reasonable notice" you are not at legal risk for breach of contract.  For specific local definition of "reasonable notice" consult a labour lawyer in your province.

The risk to your reputation exists however this is also mitigated by providing as much notice as possible.